# Jena custom datatype

Tags: java, sparql, jena, semantic-web

For a GeoSPARQL test project I want to have a custom datatype set in Jena. Howerver when I try this through [the example](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/typed-literals.html) provided at the Jena website, it still doesn't work. I get the following result:

```
_:b0 <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#asWKT> "POINT (52.83525867111958 6.870789811954563)^^http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral "^^<java:com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl> .
```

And of course I don't want the `java:com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl` but `http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral` because I wan to work with GeoSPARQL. On [this page](http://ifgi.uni-muenster.de/worldwind-tutorial/?page_id=822) they have example data that works perfectly with my triple store and spatial index. But the above data doesn't work at all with spatial indexing.

So, my question is, I do I define a custom datatype in my RDF in Jena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question after a lot of trial and error. To add a custom `RDFDatatype` to my RDF model I first had to create my own class which extends `BaseDatetype` and which I called `WktLiteral`, looking like this:

```
public class WktLiteral extends BaseDatatype {
    public static final String TypeURI = "http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral";

    public static final String CRS84 = "<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84>";

    public static final RDFDatatype wktLiteralType = new WktLiteral();

    private WktLiteral() {
        super(WktLiteral.TypeURI);
    }

    /**
     * Convert a value of this datatype out
     * to lexical form.
     */
    public String unparse(Object value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Parse a lexical form of this datatype to a value
     */
    public Object parse(String lexicalForm) {
        return new TypedValue(String.format("%s %s", WktLiteral.CRS84, lexicalForm), this.getURI());
    }

    /**
     * Compares two instances of values of the given datatype.
     * This does not allow rationals to be compared to other number
     * formats, Lang tag is not significant.
     *
     * @param value1 First value to compare
     * @param value2 Second value to compare
     * @return Value to determine whether both are equal.
     */
    public boolean isEqual(LiteralLabel value1, LiteralLabel value2) {
        return value1.getDatatype() == value2.getDatatype()
                && value1.getValue().equals(value2.getValue());
    }
```

Where it was quite important to return a `TypedLiteral` in the `parse()` method. After which I had to do the following to add something to my RDF model:

```
TypeMapper.getInstance().registerDatatype(WktLiteral.wktLiteralType);
item.addLiteral(GeoSPARQL.asWKT, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral(geom, WktLiteral.wktLiteralType));
```

Where `GeoSPARQL.asWKT` is the predicate in the GeoSPARQL vocabulary that I generated through `schemagen`. `geom` is the geometry object as well known text and `WktLiteral.wktLiteralType` is an instance of the above class.

In conclusion the result was the following (notation 3):

```
_:b0 <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat_long> "POINT (51.61821756986111 5.542408362751153)" .
```

thus exactly what I wanted... Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is

```
"POINT (52.83525867111958 6.870789811954563)"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral>
```

Comment: so, just to make it excruciatingly obvious: in the question, the closing double quotes for the literal value are in the wrong place.

Comment: Sure, I know that that is the right syntax. But how do I generate that with Jena. I tried a custom `RDFDatatype` but it doesn't seem to work. as it 'always' generates a `java:com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl` datatype.